# How to add Manim to Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, manim

I am pretty ignorant in operational systems, so I'm a bit lost in here. I've followed the manim guide installation on Windows from this youtube channel "Theorem of Beethoven". I would like to use manim on jupyter notebook, but when I try importing it, it says it isn't installed. Is there a way I can make it possible?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyter-manim)?

Comment: I hadn't seen it. Thank you very much